# Does Orbeon Form support the Thai language?

Tags: forms, orbeon, thai

I am new to Orbeon Form and would like to use it. However, I had tried the Form examples on Orbeon Form Web Site and input  some of data in Thai Language. Yes, It can be input data in the fields with “Thai Language”. But when I try to generate “PDF”. The Thai Language Data cannot be displayed.

1. Can Orbeon X-Forms Support “Thai Language” for inputting Data in the Fields ?
2. Do I need to use “Professional version” in order to get “Thai Language” to work and display on PDF generation ?
3. Can “Orbeon X-Form” be able to save Data Locally at the workstation (in case the forms are complicated to fill-in, and need several input time to finish?

Answer (score 1):

1. This is probably due to the fact that the PDF is lacking an adequate font. Since September 2011 builds, there are properties to specify font embedding, for example:

   ```
   <property as="xs:string"
       name="oxf.fr.pdf.font.path.vera"
       value="/path/to/DejaVuSans.ttf"/
   ```

   For more information, see the [documentation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Font-embedding-in-PDF-in-notemplate). Embedding a specific font with Thai characters might do the trick, although to be fair I haven't tried Thai specifically.
2. This should work equally well with both Orbeon Forms CE and PE.
3. You can do this by [adding the "Save locally" button](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Buttons-on-the-detail-page) to your forms, which is done by [setting a property in your `properties-local.xml`](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties#TOC-Overriding-properties). This will enable users to save an HTML file on their local machine. The HTML file contains all the information they entered so far: when they reopen it, they are taken back to the form on your side, with the data they entered so far "pre-filled".

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.I have tried with your suggestion as the following :

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.I have tried with your suggestion as the following :  <property as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.pdf.font.path.vera"
    value="/path/to/angsana.ttf"/    which is Thai Font in windows. But the printing the form on PDF still CANNOT show Thai chnaracters at all.   Could you please help furhter ?

Comment: And that is with a recent build, right? That property is not supported with 3.9.0 or 3.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this link for internationlization of Orbeon Forms

http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/logic/i18n

There is an example given too with multiple languages reflecting on a same form.